# jquery form related plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can you folks share the plugins that you have used for basic forms. Some of them I have used are

validation
masked input
tooltips
rounded corners
themeroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling and foudn the following links.

```
http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements
http://designm.ag/resources/jquery-form-plugins/
http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/55-jquery-form-plugins-to-download-and-use/
http://visionwidget.com/inspiration/web/494-jquery-form-plugins.html
http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/forms
```

just in case someone is looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

A large list of form plug-ins -- http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/forms

I've used the jform plugin from that list and had nice looking results